# Setting range and domain for x time axes in d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am fairly new to d3 js and I still have issues setting the axis. I am trying to set a time axis for a [horizontal floating bar chart](https://bl.ocks.org/arpitnarechania/6c2e147337d01142a27ecf111e42a380). My code looks relatively the same with the small exception that from and to are 201808, 201809 etc. (year and month).

A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sdLent50/12/) to the edited code from the example linked below. The changes are in the data set and in:

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
      .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y%b"));
```

Apparently this is not the smartest way to assign time to an axis, but I am still having issues with the domain, range and scaling of the axes.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is that you **can't** mix d3v3 and d3v4 API calls

Not

```
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
      .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y%b"));
```

But

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
    // .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y%b"))
```

A tip look at your console ans see a possible reason of the problem why you don't see stuff

To get a time axis you need to use a time scale and you need to parse the times but they are number so you might could do with

```
function NumberToDate(n) {
   return new Date(n/100, (n%100)-1, 1);
}
```

`Julyy` is with one (1) y.

How can May go from the future back in time

```
{"month": "May", "to": 201803, "from": 201812}
```

Comment: The dataset has faulty parts, but is just used to create the chart. Some other concerns that I have are the calculation of the width of the bar. It is done with ´to - from´ and as it is decent when both are from the same year, but if the years are different ( as it is the case for the second entry for January) it will cause the bar to be longer than needed